# What is an efficient way to implement 'Stack' without generics?

Tags: java, c++, programming-languages, generics, templates

Today I was reading a lot of articles complaining about Java Generics or C++ Templates. Now, my question is: How can someone implement a collection data structure like Stack without using them?

Comment: Just open the source of a JDK prior to generics and read it?

Comment: @Ordous I would appreciate if you could add a link

Comment: Quite easily - for example by either dropping type safety or the flexibility to accept multiple types.

Comment: That said, Java Generics and C++ Templates are two very different things. Don't be fooled by their deceptively similar `<>` syntax.

Comment: They both are tools that can be used to write type-independant code and having type checking at compile time.

Comment: @mahdix http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html Generics were added in Java 1.5, while `Stack` was added in 1.0. So any version from 1.0 to 1.4 should do the trick. The general idea is that they did not guarantee type safety at compile time.

Comment: Yes, but they achieve this in very different ways and provide a quite different set of features with different compile-time and run-time characteristics.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "efficient" ?  Is it the runtime performance ?  The time it takes to code the stack ? The time it takes to use it ?.  Generics generally will not make an implementation faster (runtime) but are more there to make them safer to use and more convenient.

Comment: Efficiency is in terms of writing the code. A concise and readable code.

Comment: In java priori to 1.5, a Stack was just the equivalent of a 1.5+ Stack<Object>, that's all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP correctly stated in a comment, both of these language constructs were added to their respective langugae to enable developers to write type-independent code and still provide compile-time type-safety.

Before they were added, this was not possible in these languages. You could either flexible *or* (compile-time) typesafe code, but not both. Collection types typically valued code-reuse more than compile-time type-checking and could therefore contain anything, leaving it to their users to perform runtime checks (e.g. in the form of casts).

In languages that do not provide such a feature (e.g. C), this is still the case - just have a look at their libraries.